# How to change the color of every button at once?

Tags: vb.net

I have a program that i would like the use to chose the color of their liking. I know how to change the color normally but i would like to do it all at once. is there anyway to do that? Something like if combobox.selecteditem = "Red" then
everybutton.color = color.red. Thanks for the help! Im using vb.net

Comment: Is using a loop an issue for you, something like:

For Each ctrl As Control In pnl.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        ctrl .Color = Color.Red
    End If
Next

Where pnl is the name of a panel, or some other sort of grouping control?

Comment: At least tell us what kind of program are you writing. ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF, or ??

Comment: @DanielG you can designate text as code in comments by surrounding it with back ticks. (the symbol below the tilde ~ on US keyboards.)

Comment: This is a low quality post, please add details to what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming they are all right on the form

```
Dim buttons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button).ToArray()
For each button as Button in buttons
    button.ForeColor = Color.red
Next
```

If it involves groupboxes or panels or similar, Otherwise it requires you to recursively loop through the controls check if it's a button and then set it...and then call function for it's child controls

```
Dim _list As New List(Of Control)
 Public Sub GetChilds(container As Control)
    For Each child As Control In container.Controls
        _list.Add(child)
        If (child.HasChildren) Then
            GetChilds(child)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then to populate the list you call GetChilds(Me)

And to use it

```
  For Each cntrl As Control In _list
  Dim objAsConvertible As Button = TryCast(cntrl, Button)

   If Not objAsConvertible Is Nothing Then

    objAsConvertible.ForeColor = Color.Red
   End If
Next
```

Comment: How do you know he is talking about Winform's buttons?

Comment: Combobox, otherwise it's called dropdownlist

Comment: I am using a custom theme but it is a winform button. i put the code u suggested in and put in the custom buttons like so Dim buttons = Me.Controls.OfType(Of FlatButton).ToArray()
        For Each button As FlatButton In buttons
            button.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Next

Comment: If it happens to work, please accept...or add more details so we can help better...thanks

Comment: It didnot end up working. I put that code in the form load. not sure if it matters but i am using a tab control so some buttons are in different tab pages but same tab control

Comment: You'll need a recursive loop...I'll get u the code later unless someone beats me to it

Comment: I think you meant `Dim objAsConvertible As Button = TryCast(cntrl, Button)` I changed obj to cntrl and added final paren. Upvote because I saved code for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Is using a loop an issue for you, something like:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In pnl.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then
        ctrl .Color = Color.Red
    End If
Next
```

Where pnl is the name of a panel, or some other sort of grouing control?